# Daemon Thread more than one?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

This is a very short and simple question, but couldn't get the answer from anywhere.

**More than one daemon threads can be created?**

Comment: yes, there is nothing to prevent this.

Comment: Really sorry guys, I actually tried and got 'java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException'. So I thought only one daemon thread was allowed. But after getting your replies I tried again and found that I made a stupid mistake. I called setDaemon() after starting the thread. Thanks!

Comment: The _only_ difference between a daemon thread and a non-daemon thread is what happens when the thread exits.  When a non-daemon thread exits, the JVM checks to see if it was the last one (i.e., the last non-daemon thread), and if so, the JVM shuts itself down.  When a daemon thread exits, the JVM does not perform that check.  There is no other difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can simply test it with code like

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{
    while(true){
        System.out.println("daemon1");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
});
t1.setDaemon(true);

Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{
    while(true){
        System.out.println("daemon2");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
});
t2.setDaemon(true);

t1.start();
t2.start();

try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
} catch (Exception e) {}
System.out.println("main thread stopped");
```

Output:

```
daemon1
daemon2
daemon1
daemon2
daemon1
daemon1
daemon1
daemon2
daemon1
main thread stopped
```

As you see two daemons ware running at the same time. Also since there ware no other non-daemon threads, application stopped.